# Drupal Photo Gallery Tutorial

Tags: drupal, gallery, photo

Can someone point me to a good Drupal Photo Gallery tutorial or book.  I am trying to create a photo gallery in a grid view.  However, I do not want the titles, etc. to be displayed with the photos.  Also, I want to place a border around the photos to make them stand out a bit.

I am not that well versed in PHP so I want the solution to be handled completely with modules and as little coding as possible.

Comment: You may want to try this question on Serverfault or superuser. SO is a programming site and you are trying to have a solution without coding.

Comment: The OP does not ask for a solution without coding, but as little coding as possible. He is obviously still learning php, but imho that does it mean that the question does not belong here. I think all coders try to re-use as much existing code as possible in order to be more efficient.

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/image - the image module has a photo gallery built in that might help get something up quickly.

Comment: @bkildow: True, but the general opinion seems to be that the combination of cck+imagefield+imagecache is the way forward and that image module is going away - especially since CCK will be in core in Drupal 7. See this thread: http://groups.drupal.org/node/26085.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a module that puts together the Views/CCK/Imagefield configuration for a gallery: http://drupal.org/project/views_gallery

What's great about this approach is that you then end up with a cck/views-based gallery and can easily tweak it to anything you want (like not wanting to display titles, having images pop up in a lightbox with a caption, etc.) and reuse the display of images elsewhere easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own photo gallery using Drupal modules like cck, views, imagefield and imagecache. Just search Google or Drupal.org, there are plenty of how-to's out there.

Here is a recent tutorial video: http://learnbythedrop.com/drop/148

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in learning how to use Drupal, with little/no php coding, you should take a look at [Using Drupal](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596515804) by the Lullabot team. It covers a lot of different cases, one of them is how you can build an image gallery like you describe.

Comment: Chapter 7 contains complete instructions to build a photo gallery.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial that really helped me when I was doing the same thing for the first time: http://www.primalmedia.com/blog/building-better-drupal-photo-gallery